# Webpack dev server - reloading/recompiling doesn't work

Tags: webpack

I am trying to get WDS to automatically recompile and reload my page.

My webpack config is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: './app/js/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: './public/js/index.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    publicPath: "./public",
    hot: true
  }
};
```

Accessing `localhost:8080` gives me the `index.html` page, but without any injected code. What can I do?

I am using webpack 2.2.1 webpack dev server 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the file ./public/js/index.js in your html page. For example, in this case, you need to add in the html file

```
<head>
    script src="../public/js/index.js" ></script>
<head>
```

Anyway to answer to your question one need to see your html file.